# Sharepoint 2013 site, search not working for some clients with read permissions

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

I have a couple of clients who cannot search successfully on a site where everyone else gets appropriate results.  They have adequate permissions but they get zero results, no matter what they search on.  Others with the same perms get normal results.  Any ideas?